# Can you help me to find what is going on?

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone can help to find me what is going on? I want to set the coupon redemption function.

```
<?php
    include("mysql_connect.inc.php");
    $coupon1 = $_POST['coupon1'];
    $check = $_POST['check'];
    $sql = "UPDATE coupon_table SET check='$check' WHERE coupon1='$coupon1'";      
    if(mysql_query($sql))
    {
        echo 'success!';
        echo '<meta http-equiv=REFRESH CONTENT=2;url=redempt.php>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'fail!';
        echo '<meta http-equiv=REFRESH CONTENT=2;url=redempt.php>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: What problems are you having with this code? You should also tag this **php**.

Comment: Please write descriptive titles.

Answer (score 4):

`CHECK` is a [**reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. Escape it like so:

```
UPDATE coupon_table 
SET `check` = '$check' 
WHERE coupon1 = '$coupon1';
```

**Note that:** It is always a best practice and high recommended to avoid these reserved words as object names, and not to use them.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, most likely the issue, but I would just change the name.  You will have to remember that each time.  Easier to change the field name.

Comment: @donlaur Yes you are right it is a best practice and a high recommended to avoid them as object names.